# Violin plot or box plot outside of the plot region

Tags: r, plot, violin-plot

Usually, in R, I'm able to use `xpd = NA` to add elements to an existing plot that extend outside of the plot region.

However, in this case I am trying to add violin plots or box plots, and this approach is not working.

```
library(vioplot)

# generate some data
dat <- replicate(10, rnorm(20), simplify = FALSE)

range(unlist(dat))

# first example, with all data within range
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim = c(1, 10), ylim = c(-5,5))
axis(1)
axis(2)

vioplot(dat, add = TRUE, frame.plot = FALSE)
```

[image]

Now trying to plot outside of the plotting region.

```
plot.new()
par(oma = c(3,3,3,3))
plot.window(xlim = c(1, 10), ylim = c(-10, -2))
axis(1)
axis(2)

vioplot(dat, add = TRUE, frame.plot = FALSE, xpd = NA)
boxplot(dat, add = TRUE, frame.plot = FALSE, xpd = NA)

# plot points to prove that this works with some elements
points(1:10, sapply(dat, median), xpd = NA)
```

[image]

Any ideas on how to add violin plots or box plots in such a scenario?
With box plots, I could of course easily draw them myself with `rect()` and `segments()`, but violin plots are more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `xpd=NA` globally with `par(xpd=NA)`, draw what you need with `vioplot()` or `boxplot()` and then restore the default `xpd` value with `par(xpd=F)`.

Looking in the source code, `vioplot()` ignores all graphical parameters (including `xpd`) passed to it if they are `NA`. You could in theory use `xpd=T` but this is unfortunately not passed to all the lower level drawing functions. `boxplot()` (or rather its workhorse `bxp()`) does not seem to pass `xpd` to any of the drawing functions it uses.